# Why CSS and browsers dosn't reload the changes at all?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a website following a tutorial of a programmer, I really adored the way he teach how to make a full responsive website with Html, Css and JavaScript

The problem is when  I refresh my webpage to see the change while I m following he's steps, for him everything change slightly but for me nothing happen at all

I verified the codes in both html and Css around five times, everything goes similar with what he wrote.

I linked correctly html with css

I m using both Visual Studio Code and Brackets

I cleared the cache and cookies in order to force the Css works properly but everything the same still

I pressed the disable cookies on chrome Developer Tools window and I kept it opened

I changed the Laptop to another one with a great performance (thinkpad, i5 generation) all browsers are empty caches, cookies and histories

Unfortunately we all this attempts still the same problem

I dont know either the browsers (chrome and Mozilla) are the problem or the css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin|Herr+Von+Muellerhoff|Source+Sans+Pro:400,900&display=swap');
/*Global styles*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    --main-font: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    --secondary-font: 'Herr Von Muellerhoff', cursive;
    --body-font: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    --main-font-color-dark: #252525;
    --secondary-font-color: #c59d5f;
    --body-font-color: #515151;
}

html {
    font-family: var(--body-font);
    font-size: 10px;
    color: var(--body-font-color);
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
    padding: 3.9rem 0;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 122.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2.4rem;
}

/*header*/
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0, 0, 0, .5), transparent);
}

.nav {
    height: 7.2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.menu-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 2.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalabel=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TheElegantTaste</title>
    <!--Font awesome CDN-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <!--Scroll reveal CDN-->
    <script scr="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="nav">
                <div class="menu-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="TheElegantTaste.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Reservations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--Header End-->
    <section class="hero" id="hero">
       <div class="container">
           <h2 class="sub-headline">
               <span class="first-letter">W</span>elcome
           </h2>
           <h1 class="headline">The Elegant Taste</h1>
           <div class="headline-description">
               <div class="separator">
                   <div class="line line-left"></div>
                   <div class="asterisk"><i class="fas fa-asterisk"></i></div>
                   <div class="line line-right"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="single-animation">
                   <h5>Ready to be opened</h5>
                   <a href="#" class="btn cta-btn"></a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </section>
<!--Hero Ends-->
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I got when I reload the browser (Chrome or Mozilla)

The website I'm following the steps in order if someone want to match the first part from the codes in both Html & Css in both files

Build a Responsive Website with Animations | HTML 5 and CSS 3 Tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZQxPTV3cFk&ab_channel=JulioCodes

Comment: What's the problem you are talking about?

Comment: Maybe try CTRL+F5?

Comment: CSS is cached in the browser so if you want to see changes you have to clear that browser cache (control + Shift + delete on a PC). Depending on the website host you have you can clear the cache on the server so everyone sees the same changes. Caching improves page performance but also means once loaded the browser doesn't load a new css file again until the server tells it to.

Comment: I cleared the cache but it still the same that's what made me more clueless

Comment: Are you sure that you are editing the correct CSS file? Did you move your folder somewhere else but yet, kept your IDE on your "old" location or something similar?

Comment: I keep the css file in the same file with index.html and main.js, I m put it in desktop

Comment: Ok, then open the *network* tab open on the devtools (on Chrome) and refresh the page. Then you should have a list of files that were downloaded, what does it appear on the size column of your CSS file, memory cache or the size file? If memory appeared, then it is a cache issue, otherwise, your changes are not being made to the file itself.

Comment: I m sure css linked with html because when i open a div to style it showed the path of the div linked to html